# Skybox texture not showing in DirectX9

Tags: directx-9, skybox

I am trying to render a skybox in DirectX9 with fixed function pipeline (without shader or effect file). I can view the cube rendering. When I set the texture all faces are getting painted with a single strange color (not white or blank). The texture file is a correct cube map.I think some texture setting is not set. Below is the code snippet

`// for creating the cube and the cube texture`

`HRESULT apiResult = D3DXCreateBox(g_pd3dDevice,1,1,1,&g_pMesh,NULL);`

`apiResult = D3DXCreateCubeTextureFromFile(g_pd3dDevice,L"cubeMap.dds",&g_pTexture);`

both APIs are returning S_OK.

`// for renderin the skybox`

`g_pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0,D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER,D3DTEXF_LINEAR);`
`g_pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0,D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER,D3DTEXF_LINEAR);`
`g_pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0,D3DSAMP_MINFILTER,D3DTEXF_LINEAR);`

`// set texture`

`g_pd3dDevice->SetTexture(0,g_pTexture);`

`// Begin the scene`
`if( SUCCEEDED( g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene() ) )`

`{`

`g_pMesh->DrawSubset(0);`

`g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();`

`}`

`// Present the backbuffer contents to the display`

`g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );`

Which setting is missing ?

Comment: What's the reason for not using the programmable pipeline?

Comment: @uberwulu:Using HLSL did it successfully, just need to check what is going wrong in fixed function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but try lowering the resolution of the image you are loading, i had a similar problem once and found out that the image couldn't load because of that, the resolution was too big.

Comment: thanks for the hint,but image loading is not the problem in my case same texture is working fine when used in programmable pipeline.